# Minimize $a+b+c+d$ given $\text{LCM}(a,b,c,d)=1000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

It is the inverse of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846896/111704) problem.

> Minimize $a+b+c+d$ given $a, b, c, d$ are distinct positive integers, and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c,d) =1000$.

Of course, it would be possible to enumerate all quadruplets with $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c,d)=1000$, however it might be interesting to see whether there is a more intelligent approach. Or even if the minimum is found by an exhaustive search, at least the bound can possibly be proved more directly. (As in the answer to the post which inspired this: [Minimize $LCM(a,b,c,d)$ given $a+b+c+d=1000$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846896).)

Since $1000=2^3\cdot5^3$, we will need at least one of the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ to contain factor $2^3$. And, similarly, at least one of them has to contain $5^3$.

Comment: First I understood that problem on this way, and now I am curious, what would be the solution if I had understood it correctly.

Comment: Is this one of those "you know the answer but you want to post the question anyway" problems?

Comment: @DanielV I don't know the solution, probably I could find it with a little work, but I am curious and I think, it would be an interesting challenge also for others :-)

Comment: Next time you want to reopen a question, instead of arguing endlessly with people, try to improve the post first. It will be much more effective.

Comment: @YuiToCheng It is not so simple - in my opinion, there is a retroactively applied rule, which is used as an excuse for rule-violating content deletion. But it is only my version - I would suggest to talk more about it on the site chat.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Well, thank you very much your votes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least one of $a,b,c,d$ must be divisible by $5^3$ and at least one must be divisible by $2^3$.  Any extra factors can be eliminated, reducing $a+b+c+d$.
Since $1+2^3 \cdot 5^3 > 2^3 + 5^3$, the optimal solution is $1,\; 1,\; 2^3,\; 5^3$.

Comment: Wow! It was easier as I've tought on the first spot. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since $1000=2^35^3$, we know that among the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ at least one must have the factor of $2^3$ and another must have the factor $5^3$ (by the definition of LCM). They are either the same number or different ones.

If they are the same number, WLOG<sup>1</sup> let this be $a$. So $a+b+c+d\geq 2^35^3+1+1+1=1003$, which is achievable when $a=1000$ and $b=c=d=1$.

If they are different numbers, WLOG let $8\mid a$ and $125\mid b$. Then $a+b+c+d \geq 135$ which is achievable when $a=8$, $b=125$, and $c=d=1$.

Overall, the smallest possible value is $135$.

<sup>1</sup>Without loss of generality.

Answer (score 1):

Prime factorisation of $1000$ is $2^3\cdot5^3$ so how about $$a=1,\quad b=1,\quad c=2^3,\quad d=5^3$$ which gives $a+b+c+d=135$?

Comment: How to know that it is the smallest?

Comment: Fix $a=b=1$ as they are the smallest possible. Now experiment with different values of $c$ and $d$...